# Remove a JList List Selection Listener that was added using a Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, jlist, listselectionlistener

I added a JList Selection Listener using a Lambda and I find I need to remove the listener while doing an operation. I haven't seen any examples on how to do this. I ended up using an older method of creating a Listener and saving a reference to it.

Comment: A lambda object will be the same as any other object. It's better to have the listener check whether it should proceed than temporarily removing it.

Comment: I tried to remove the listener the same as adding it but it didn't get removed. Adding logic to check if the listener could proceed proved to be quite complex so it was easier and less prone to errors to just remove the listener. Under the covers it's just adding or removing items from a List which in the GUI world that time is quick